# Objective-C this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key findContact.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with app I made using **[this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_7_Application).**

Everything seems fine, but when I build, there is an error :

```
2014-08-28 11:49:20.038 techtopiatut[1551:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x8c4dd00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key findContact.'
```

If someone would want to see project, it is **[here](http://speedy.sh/quBMJ/techtopiatut.zip).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of invalid outlets.

If you remove `saveData` in `Referencing Outlets` here

[image]

and remove `findContact` in `Referencing Outlets` here

[image]

Comment: Just realised that references dont magically disappear. THANK YOU!

Comment: @AlanKałuża You're welcome. Would appreciate an upvote. But I think Rashad beats my answer in term of time. You probably should accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You've deleted some button, but reference is still there. See this:

[image]

Go to your storyboard, then delete the yellow marked ref. This will work. Then it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Really thank you! Cant even upvote that. Really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that problem... your buttons `Save` and `Find` are still referencing your FileOwner delete the reference and thats it...

For more details see the image and click the x exactly pointed by the arrow. Continue the same practice for `Save` too.

[image]

Comment: Thaths is awesome. Thanks for being so accurate. Thank you.

Comment: @AlanKałuża, accept an answer which you have found useful.